# uncaught typeerror object has no method "tooltip"

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I am trying to view tool tip on Text box using Jquery scripts on a web form using Master Page. When I rum my code everything seems working fine,but in DOM of Google chrome browser,the resources folder i get the above error.
I am not able to figure out where i am wrong.

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" CssClass="UserName"></asp:TextBox>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $(".UserName").tooltip();
    });
</script>
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: It's telling you the tooltip plugin isn't loaded.

Comment: Can you show where you load your `tooltip` plugin?

Comment: You need to include `<script src="path_to_tooltip_plugin.js"></script>`

Comment: Maybe you include jquery after the plugin or maybe you have two jquery script, one after the plugin, which will remove it from jQuery object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you correctly included jQuery UI

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Comment: Then make sure the order is right. I mean http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7604980/trying-to-use-jquery-tooltip-plugin-object-has-no-method-tooltip